# LINUX freezing pdo exeption error

Tags: mysql, linux

We are using RHEL 6.5 on our production server, it works fine before starting mysqld service once we start this service system starts freezing , i even tried through mysqld_safe to start the service how can i fix this problem in order to up mywebsite

Comment: A starting point could be to check the error logs of mysql

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.